# Постановка запятой перед И

Tags: пунктуация

Здравствуйте! Скажите, пожалуйста, верно ли я поставила запятую перед союзом "и". Или же в данном случае запятая не нужна? "Навстречу мне шли две улыбающиеся девушки. Мы поравнялись друг с другом, и они скрылись из виду".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запятая нужна. Это сложное предложение. Мы поравнялись... Они ушли.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 0):

> **Мы поравнялись** друг с
>   другом, и **они скрылись** из виду.

Запятая-то нужна -- для разделения частей сложносочинённого предложения. Да...

Бессмысленное оно какое-то.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!